# PetaPoco GetInstance() always return new instance?

Tags: database, orm, petapoco

Just have a question regarding PetaPoco generated Database.cs code from version 4.0.3. See below code snippet:

```
public partial class postgresqlDB : Database
{
    public postgresqlDB() 
        : base("postgresql")
    {
        CommonConstruct();
    }

    public postgresqlDB(string connectionStringName) 
        : base(connectionStringName)
    {
        CommonConstruct();
    }

    partial void CommonConstruct();

    public interface IFactory
    {
        postgresqlDB GetInstance();
    }

    public static IFactory Factory { get; set; }
    public static postgresqlDB GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance!=null)
            return _instance;

        if (Factory!=null)
            return Factory.GetInstance();
        else
            return new postgresqlDB();
    }

    [ThreadStatic] static postgresqlDB _instance;

    public override void OnBeginTransaction()
    {
        if (_instance==null)
            _instance=this;
    }

    public override void OnEndTransaction()
    {
        if (_instance==this)
            _instance=null;
    }
.....
..... <snip />
```

Looking at the `GetInstance()` function, why is it that the `return new postgresqlDB()` is never assigned to the private variable `_instance`?

Doesn't this mean every call to `GetInstance()` will always create a new instance because `if (_instance != null) return _instance;` will never be true?

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Do you have the code for CommonConstruct() ? I would assume it might be setting the variable there

Comment: It's generated code by PetaPoco via TT templates. Out of the box, this is all there is. I am just curious as to why there is no assignment to `_instance` in the generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this behavior today as well with PetaPoco.  (Hat's off to the creator(s) since it is generally a pleasure to use!).  In a related situation, I wanted to pull a copy of the most recent sql passed through PetaPoco in order to review it with code like:

```
Console.WriteLine(RepositoryTableClass.repo.LastCommand);
```

In my case it was always empty for exactly the reason as OP suggests.  The threadstatic marker is orthogonal to the original question.  The only place in code where the _instance variable is set is for the duration of a transaction.  As a result each instance of the repository is used and abandoned by default.  (This may be to avoid problems with re-using the single connection for multiple overlapping queries\results?)

In any case the factory pattern is available and can be used to force reliance on a single repo instance if that is what you desire.  Try a super simple factory class like:

```
private class RepoFactory : postgresqlDB.IFactory
{
        private static postgresqlDB repo = postgresqlDB.GetInstance();

        public postgresqlDB GetInstance()
        {
            return repo;
        }
}
```

Set the factory before you begin using any repository objects like so:

```
postgresqlDB.Factory = new RepoFactory();
```

That enabled me to use repository objects against a single repository instance as verified by having a populated value for the last command after each usage...

```
RepositoryTableClass.repo.LastCommand
```

Comment: Your approach is similar to ours as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've attributed the _instance field with ThreadStatic.  That means there's a different value in the field for each thread use to access it.  If GetInstance is always called with a new thread, it will always have a new value (in other words, call the constructor each time)

Comment: I see. What if `GetInstance()` is called multiple times while within the same thread for some reason? Then in this scenario, in each call it will always return a new `postgresqlDB` instance?

Comment: From the same thread, it call the constructor the first time then return the same value subsequent times  I would recommend using Lazy<T> instead of using an instance field though...

Comment: If we look at the `GetInstance()` implementation, in the `else return new postgresqlDB();` statement, it doesn't seem to ever set the local `_instance` variable to the created instance. So even if in the same thread, doesn't it also keep returning new instances of `postgresqlDB`?